# Как получить адреса инструкций IL (IL_xxxx)

Tags: c#, opcode

Хочу на консоль вывести IL код, который генерируется при выполнении тела метода. Я делаю это, но результат меня не до конца устраивает. Проблема состоит в том, что я не знаю как выводить строку вместе с адресами `IL_xxxx`.

Вот мой код:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var mi = typeof(Program).GetMethod("Method");

    byte[] msil = mi.GetMethodBody().GetILAsByteArray();

    FieldInfo[] opCodesInstructions = typeof(OpCodes).GetFields();
    for (int i = 0; i < opCodesInstructions.Length; i++)
    {
        if (i == msil.Length)
            break;
        var instruction = (OpCode)opCodesInstructions[i].GetValue(null);
        var member = opCodesInstructions.FirstOrDefault(x => ((OpCode)x.GetValue(null)).Value == msil[i]);
        var currentIL = (OpCode)member.GetValue(null);
        Console.WriteLine($"{currentIL.Name}");
    }
}

public void Method()
{
    int a = 5;
    int b = 9;
    string str = (a + b).ToString();
}
```

На вывод я получаю

```
nop
ldc.i4.5
stloc.0
...
```

А получать хочу вот в таком формате (не знаю где мне взять эти адреса):

```
IL_0000: nop
IL_0001: ldc.i4.5
IL_0002: stloc.0
...
```

Comment: это разве не просто номер строки?

Comment: @Grundy я не уверен, поскольку они идут не по порядоку (1, 2, 3, 5, 6, b...). Отсутствует 4-ка, поэтому я в замешательстве. Если будет еще один участок IL, то он будет нумероваться тоже странно (0, 1, 6, 7). Можете посмотреть вот [тут](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LglgNgNAJiDUAfAAgJgIwFgBQyDMABGgQMIEDeOB1RhyALAQLICmwAFgPYwAUAlFRqVsNUWAB2wAgEMCAXgIBWANyDRBCVIBG8ggE5VI9QQDyWgFYsAxlKu6ARNIDOMAGb3Dxouj09Z8Ai0+TxoAXwIcUKA===)

Comment: да :-) оказывается там все несколько интереснее

Comment: Эмм... Ну так инструкция может занимать более одного байта в памяти, это не лейблы, а адреса по которым расположены инструкции.

Comment: Адрес из ildasm - это просто порядковый номер начального байта инструкции в вашем массиве msil. Вопрос только в том, зачем вам этот номер, если вы не парсите само содержимое байткода, в том числе операнды. Ваш самодельный парсер на вызове `ToString` начнет врать, ибо у инструкции будет 4-байтовый операнд, который вы не учитываете...

Comment: Присоединяюсь к предыдущему комментарию - а зачем оно вообще надо? Может не надо?

Comment: @aepot я делаю это только из личного интереса, полезно знать, что там внутри происходит

Comment: Ну как выше сказали, надо считать операнды, то есть более глубокий анализ делать.

Comment: @aepot а что может дать анализ операндов? я знаю, можно вручную оптимизировать IL, а что с операндами? Или может я неправильно понял смысл предложения

Comment: Индексы посчитать, которые вам так нужны.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В общем дело обстоит не так просто как предпологалось мне до этого, так что я взял библиотеку [`Mono.Reflection`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Mono.Reflection/), И все получилось:

```
namespace ori;

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Mono.Reflection;

static class Application {
    static void Main() {
        typeof(Application)
            .GetMethod(nameof(Method))
            .GetInstructions()
            .ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
    }

    public static void Method() {
        int a = 5;
        int b = 9;
        string str = (a + b).ToString();
    }

    public static void ForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> e, Action<T> a) {
        foreach(T item in e) {
            a(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Вывод:

```
IL_0000: nop
IL_0001: ldc.i4.5
IL_0002: stloc.0
IL_0003: ldc.i4.s 9
IL_0005: stloc.1
IL_0006: ldloc.0
IL_0007: ldloc.1
IL_0008: add
IL_0009: stloc.3
IL_000a: ldloca.s System.Int32 (3)
IL_000c: call System.String ToString()
IL_0011: stloc.2
IL_0012: ret
```

Для понимания почему я использовал библиотеку, прошу взглянуть на исходный: https://github.com/jbevain/mono.reflection/

Comment: За что минус? Откройте секрет.

Comment: Не я минус ставил, спасибо, частично решает проблему. А как бы вы выводили инструкции?

Comment: Ладно, сейчас допишу код, и выложу рабочую нормальную версию. Там кстати еще нужно смотреть OpCodeType

Comment: Так, все немного усложнилось, напишу до 24 по мск.

Comment: спасибо Вам огромное :)